# Apacite: Citation prints citekey in addition to reference

Tags: bibtex, citing, texmaker, apacite

I'm using TexMaker to write my thesis and have previously written a paper with the same setup. I created a new bibliography for my thesis and it prints the list of references just fine, however, when citing in text (using \cite) the citation key is printed before the actual reference like so:

> (horberg2011emotionsHorberg,Oveis & Keltner, 2011)

is printed instead of

> (Horberg, Oveis & Keltner, 2011)

I used the same commands as in my last paper where everything worked fine. Now I'm confused why the citation key is included.

Thanks in advance for any help!

MWE:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{a4}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{pict2e}
 \usepackage{graphpap}
 \usepackage{apacite}
 \usepackage{subfigure}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{wasysym}
 \usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}
 \usepackage{epsfig}
 \usepackage{epic}
 \usepackage{exscale,latexsym}
 \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \usepackage[flushmargin,hang]{footmisc}
 \usepackage[dvipdfm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{titlesec}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{url}
 \usepackage{prettyref}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \usepackage{cancel}
 \usepackage{acronym}

 \makeatletter
 \makeatother
 \renewcommand\refname{References}
 \flushbottom 

 \onehalfspacing
 \parindent 0pt 
 \begin{document}
 \pagenumbering{Roman}
 \raggedbottom

 \newpage\pagenumbering{arabic}
 \section{Introduction}
 Text\\ \cite{horberg2011emotions}
 \newpage\pagenumbering{Roman}

 \newpage
 \bibliographystyle{apacite}
 \bibliography{referencesipdm}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you checked that the compilation doesn't give any errors? Also, please add a minimal but complete example document that replicates the problem.

Comment: Please confirm that you use the `apacite` bibliography style and the `apacite` citation management package.

Comment: I added a MWE above. When compiling I only get a warning message; 

/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty 
"Drivers other than pdftex and luatex are not supported"

When compiling with Bibtex it says process excited normally.

Comment: I have no problem. Show your bibliography data for `horberg2011emotions`

Comment: `@article{horberg2011emotions,
  title={Emotions as moral amplifiers: An appraisal tendency approach to the influences of distinct emotions upon moral judgment},
  author={Horberg, Elizabeth J and Oveis, Christopher and Keltner, Dacher},
  journal={Emotion Review},
  volume={3},
  number={3},
  pages={237--244},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Sage Publications Sage UK: London, England}
}`

That's the bibtex citation from Google Scholar which I just copied in my bib file. Did so for all references